# swap elements in array using void pointer

Tags: c, function, types

i need to write a function

```
void reverse(void *base, int nel, int width) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

where base is the pointer to the start of the array, nel - number of elements in the array, and width is the size of each element in bytes.

For example, how can I swap first two elements of the array?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: first start writing `void reverse(char *base, size_t nel, size_t width) { ... }`. Than convert it to void pointer type.

Comment: Please post the code that you've written so far. Is there a *specific* problem you're having? An error you're receiving? An incorrect behavior?

Comment: How does the title of the question reflect the content of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `memcpy` (since it is a builtin on many compilers), with the help of `width` value. You also need a temporary variable.

```
/* C99 (use `malloc` rather than VLAs in C89) */
#include <string.h>

void reverse(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width) 
{
    if (nel >= 2) {
        char *el1 = base;
        char *el2 = (char *)base + width;
        char tmp[width];

        memcpy(tmp, el1, width);
        memcpy(el1, el2, width);
        memcpy(el2, tmp, width);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just `swap()`? If called with e.g. 5 elements, it won't actually reverse them from what I can see.

Comment: Bear in mind  
    char tmp[width]
Is gcc specific, i.e. not standard C !

Comment: @unwind: As far I can see, it was the question of the OP (how to swap the contents of the first two elements of the array).

Comment: @Neil: Aren't VLAs C99 standard ?

Comment: @Neil VLA are perfectly standard in C99 as mentioned by Kirilenko (see section 6.7.5.2)

Comment: @Virgile My bad.  gcc supports C99, but I believe VS doesn't. (does that get me out of the hole :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you you want it type generic, use

```
void swap(void *base, int len, int width)
{
    void *p = malloc(width);

    memcpy(p,base,width);
    memcpy(base,(char*)base+width,width);
    memcpy((char*)base+width,p,width);

    free(p);
}
```

This will swap the first 2 elements.